# Why is "himself" used here?

Tags: relative-pronouns, case

> You look like Mr Johnson himself.

Why is "oneself" used in this case?
What usage is this?
I would like a grammatical source.

Comment: Could  you give us more context please?

Comment: As it is given, *himself* looks redundant.

Comment: @MaulikV But although some redundancy is undesirable, other redundancy is not.  Here, *himself* is used for emphasis.  This is what is sometimes called an **emphatic pronoun**.  It differs from a **reflexive pronoun** in that it can be removed without altering the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @snailplane BobRodes already wrote it, which I got.

Comment: No, BobRodes did not write the same thing I did.  Anyway, if you feel your comment has been made obsolete by his answer, please delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is indeed redundant as Maulik says.  However, its intention is to emphasize the person or thing to which it refers, and there is an element of surprise associated with it.  "While we were sitting in the bar this evening, who walked in but John himself, five years to the day after his shipwreck.  You could have knocked me over with a feather; we had all been sure that he was dead."

That would be an extreme example.  A less extreme example is "How do you know where that quote comes from?  Because I wrote it myself."  This emphasizes the fact that I wrote it, because the context suggests that it contradicts the expectation of the questioner.